# Returning a @Bean through @Configuration on its own class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring-ioc

I have the following class:

```
@Configuration
@Component
@Getter
public class EndUserDisambiguator extends UserDisambiguator {
    private final Collection<UserCredentialDisambiguator<?, ?, ?>> endUserCredentialDisambiguators;

    @Autowired
    public EndUserDisambiguator(final EndUserRepository userRepository) {
        super(userRepository);

        val phoneNumberDisambiguator = new UserCredentialDisambiguator<>(EndUser::getPhoneNumber, userRepository::findByPhoneNumber, PhoneNumberExistsException::new);
        val socialSecurityNumberDisambiguator = new UserCredentialDisambiguator<>(EndUser::getSocialSecurityNumber, userRepository::findBySocialSecurityNumber, SocialSecurityNumberExistsException::new);

        this.endUserCredentialDisambiguators = Set.of(phoneNumberDisambiguator, socialSecurityNumberDisambiguator);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<UserCredentialDisambiguator<?, ?, ?>> getUserCredentialDisambiguators() {
        val baseCredentialDismabiguators = super.getUserCredentialDisambiguators().stream();
        val specificUserCredentialDisambiguators = getEndUserCredentialDisambiguators().stream();

        val userCredentialDisambiguators = Stream.concat(baseCredentialDismabiguators, specificUserCredentialDisambiguators);

        return userCredentialDisambiguators.collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    }

    @Bean(UserDisambiguator.END_USER_QUALIFIER)
    public EndUserDisambiguator getEndUserDisambiguator() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is part of the disambiguation layer of my application, the layer that ensures any unpersisted users created in the service layer do not interfere with existing persisted users (for example, ensuring usernames are unique). `

It therefore is `@Autowired` a reference to a user repository, and only the disambiguation layer is `@Autowired` a repository (the service layer is not). The service layer does its persisting through the disambiguation layer.

`EndUserService` (the corresponding service for the same type of user) therefore requires an `@Autowired` reference to `EndUserDisambiguator`. I do not want to leak the repository layer to service layer (the service layer does its persisting post-disambiguation). **Is it a design flaw to declare `EndUserDisambiguator` a `@Configuration` and have a method returning a `@Bean` corresponding to itself?**

Here is where `EndUserDisambiguator` is injected into:

```
@Service
public class EndUserService extends UserService {
    @Autowired
    public EndUserService(final VerificationTokenRepository verificationTokenRepository, final EndUserDisambiguator userDisambiguator) {
        super(verificationTokenRepository, userDisambiguator);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: how do you resolve a conflict between two beans (the `@Bean` method and the `@Component` class are of the same type)

Comment: Could you show 2 places where you inject `UserDisambiguator`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko ah, that was a typo on my end, I've changed the bean return type to the implementation `EndUserDisambiguator` from the abstraction `UserDisambiguator`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I don't inject `UserAmbiguator` directly, that's the abstraction. However, I inject `EndUserDisambiguator` into and only into `EndUserService`, editing that into the question